# Overflow-x as Hidden Doesn't Work with Absolutely Positioned Elements

Tags: html, css

I have a couple of elements that are `position:absolute;left:200%;` on a page. The `left:200%;` is intended to keep the element out of sight but still allow for the element to appear from the right-hand side with a transition.

The relevant CSS for my `body` and `html` elements is as follows:

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    }
body {
    min-height:100%;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    }
```

When the page loads, it looks fine. There is no horizontal scroll bar but there is a vertical one. However, when pressing the middle mouse button or pressing the right arrow on the keyboard, I'm still able to scroll to the right, revealing the elements.

I've read that a solution to this is to add `overflow-x:hidden;` to the `html` element, but when I do this, some other `position:absolute;` page elements overlap the vertical scroll bar and begin to act like `position:fixed;` elements (they don't scroll with the rest of the page but instead stay in the same position with the window).

I've also read that it's possible to use JavaScript to fix the horizontal scrolling problem, but I can't find a good example or full explanation, either on StackOverflow or anywhere else.

How do I fix this, preferably with CSS, but JavaScript if necessary, while keeping all else on the page as is (importantly `position:absolute;` still acting that way)?

Comment: try to add position relative to your container. you can create a fiddle so that we can help you more or rather paste the link of the website

Comment: @winresh24 On adding `position:relative;` it seems like that works. Thanks!